# How can I remove lines that contain more than N words

Tags: string, bash

Is there a good one-liner in bash to remove lines containing more than N words from a file?

example input:

```
I want this, not that, but thank you it is very nice of you to offer.
The very long sentence finding form ordering system always and redundantly requires an initial, albeit annoying and sometimes nonsensical use of commas, completion of the form A-1 followed, after this has been processed by the finance department and is legal, by a positive approval that allows for the form B-1 to be completed after the affirmative response to the form A-1 is received.
```

example output:

```
I want this, not that, but thank you it is very nice of you to offer.
```

In Python I would code something like this:

```
if len(line.split()) < 40:
    print line
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To only show lines containing less than 40 words, you can use awk:

```
awk 'NF < 40' file
```

Using the default field separator, each word is treated as a field. Lines with less than 40 fields are printed.

Answer (score 4):

#### Note this answer assumes the first approach of the question: how to print those lines being shorter than a given number of characters

Use `awk` with `length()`:

```
awk 'length($0)<40' file
```

You can even give the length as a parameter:

```
awk -v maxsize=40 'length($0) < maxsize' file
```

---

A test with 10 characters:

```
$ cat a
hello
how are you
i am fine but
i would like
to do other
things
$ awk 'length($0)<10' a
hello
things
```

If you feel like using `sed` for this, you can say:

```
sed -rn '/^.{,39}$/p' file
```

This checks if the line contains less than 40 characters. If so, it prints it.

Comment: no. they are not the same. python's `str.split` returns a result of list. op counts the number of elements in the list, but you only counts the characters.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr the OP mentions `len(line.split())`, so I don't know what are you talking about. Note, however, that in the original question it was just `line.split()`, so maybe this lead to a confusion.

Comment: sorry about the confusion, you answered before I could correct my mistake.  Very fast! Compliments!

Comment: @fedorqui `len('how are you'.split()) < 10` returns `True`. but you've filtered that out

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr well I didn't go through the Python code very thoroughly, just got the idea of printing lines shorter than a given number of characters. OP mentions this solves it, so I still wonder the reason of the downvote  : )

Comment: This is a great response.  However I am still not 100% there. What about for words in a string separated by white space?  so 40 words instead of characters?

Comment: @badner if it is about words, check Tom Fenech's answer. He just updated with such info!